# Пунктуация - неотъемлемая часть русского языка

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Уважаемые любители русского языка, уделите, пожалуйста, минуту своего времени.

Передо мной стоит задача - подтянуть пунктуационную часть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы, благодаря которым можно это сделать? Читал Лопатина и Розенталя, но не очень понял то, что там доносится. Быть может, есть отдельные источники, где простым языком написано то или иное правило, которое поясняет правильность написания.

Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Справочники Розенталя и Лопатина — это именно справочники. К ним обращаются за разрешением недоумений. Учиться по справочникам затруднительно. Для этого лучше взять самые обычные учебники по русскому языку за 10-11 классы. Любые, какие входят в Федеральный перечень учебников.
Если же вам нужны именно электронные ресурсы, то [вот](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/gramota/punct) и [вот](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya.html).

Comment: Грамота.ру классный ресурс, но тоже с подковырками. Исследую второй предложенный источник. Надеюсь, что он не подведет и будет надежным проводником :)

Comment: @ve2nra учебник "Грамоты" хорош тем, что прост и что в конце каждой темы имеется ряд упражнений с автоматической проверкой правильности. В учебнике же Лицея нет автоматической проверки, там есть только упражнения для самопроверки (с ответами): https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/42-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_uprazhneniya.html

Comment: @ven2ra почта в профиле.